# Sequelize Invalid value [object Promise] using assocations

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

My current models:

```
let Book = sequelize.define('book', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  author: Sequelize.STRING,
  ...
});

let Recommendation = sequelize.define('recommendations', {
  reasoning: Sequelize.STRING,
  rating: Sequelize.FLOAT,
});

Book.belongsToMany(Recommendation, {through: 'bookrecommendation'});
Recommendation.belongsToMany(Book, {through: 'bookrecommendation'});
```

When executing code below method addRecommendation to add Recommendation for Book I get an error Error: Invalid value [object Promise]

```
Book.findOrCreate({
  where: { id: '1' }, defaults: {
    author: 'test',
    title: 'test'
  }
})
.spread(function (b, createdBook) {
const rec = Recommendation.create(
  {
    reasoning: 'test',
    rating: 1
  });
  b.addRecommendation(rec).then((result) => {

  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that `rec` is a promise.
This should solve the issue

```
Book.findOrCreate({ where: { id: '1' }, defaults: {
  author: 'test',
  title: 'test'
}}).spread(function (b, createdBook) {
Recommendation.create({
 reasoning: 'test',
 rating: 1
}).then((rec) => {
  b.addRecommendation(rec).then((result) => {}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
   })
})
```

Comment: Of course it works, I didn't think of that one. Thanks.